# Refactoring multiple switch statements with a more Elegant code

Tags: .net, c#-2.0

In my application, i have to perform many tasks based on a variable value(**m_iIndex**) in many of my methods.
For achieving it i use switch case statements in most of my methods

For ex :

```
MathMethod()
{
   switch(m_iIndex)
   {
    case 0 : CallAddition(); break; 
    case 1 : CallSubtraction(); break;
    case 2 : CallMultiplication(); break;
    case 3 : CallDivision(); break;
   }
}


StrangeMethod()
{
   switch(m_iIndex)
   {
    case 0 : CallStrange(10,"John"); break; 
    case 1 : CallStrange(20,"Paul"); break;
    case 2 : CallStrange(30,"Kurt"); break;
    case 3 : CallStrange(40,"Mark"); break;
   }
}
```

This continues for some 10 more methods. I was wondering is there a way to make this code more elegant and short, by reducing the switch case statements in all my methods.

Answer (score 2):

Try using Polymorphism and create a class per operation. This is called the [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).

I can only guess on how you set `m_iIndex`, but the following example demonstrates what I mean:

```
abstract class Operation
{
    abstract void Execute();
}

class Addition : Operation
{
    public override void Execute()
    {
      // ...
    }
}

// same for Subtraction etc.

void OnAdditionButtonClicked(...)
{
    // Instead of setting m_iIndex to 0, use this instead:
    _operation = new Addition();
}
```

If you provide more context, I can change my example to better meet your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The scenario is ...based on a menu item selection in my UI Class, i use the selected index value to decide on calling different methods. Isn't subclassing introduces too much overhead in my case ?

Comment: I don't know. That is up to you to decide. Performance overhead is not a problem. But maybe it is over engineering in a simple case like yours. But I certainly wouldn't do it like you did it with switch cases. You could create one class per index, i.e. one for 1, one for two, each with a `MathMethod` and a `StrangeMethod` and one for each of your other 10 methods. Like this you would have only 4 classes instead of 4 * 12 = 48 classes.

Comment: I'm sorry i didnt get the part where you are infering to 48 classes. In my case all the other methods which are called from the case statement reside in the same class. As you have pointed out this could be a case of over engineering for a very simple case like mine

Comment: My answer told you to create one class per operation, i.e. one class for addition, one for subtraction, one for `CallStrange(10,"John")`, one for `CallStrange(20,"Paul")` and so on. If you have 12 methods which contain a switch with 4 branches you have 4 * 12 = 48 different method calls and hence 48 classes. As I said in my last comment, this can be reduced to 4 classes.

Comment: BTW: The approach provided by my answer is called the [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).

Answer (score 2):

Lets assume your methods `MathMethod()` and `StrangeMethod()` as well as the member `m_iIndex` are part of a class `YourClass`. Try to eliminate `m_iIndex`; instead, use sub classes of `YourClass` where `MathMethod` and `StrangeMethod` are virtual and get overriden in your subclasses.

[Here](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism)
you will find a more elaborate answer.